# Cannot access my Derby database after I shut down Netbeans

Tags: java, derby

I have problem with executing a jar file that creates a derby connection.

I am using netbeans; while netbeans is open the jar is executed correctly, but when I close the netbeans then I cannot connect to the database. This gives an error that the database is not found.

Code is as follows:

```
try
{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample","app","app");

        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from login");

    while(rs.next())
    {
        username[i] = rs.getString(3);
        password[i] =rs.getString(8);
                    i++;
    }
}
catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
```

Jar execution error is

> java.sql.SQLNoonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectionException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 1527 with massage Connection refused : connect

What should I do to correct the problem?

Comment: You should show your code, and copy and paste the error message you get

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans is running Derby for you. Look under Services->Databases->Java DB (probably under Java DB). When NB starts the DB, your application connects to that instance, and it's fine.

When you shut down Netbeans, it stops the Derby server and your application won't run. So you either need to switch to an embedded Derby configuration, or run a Derby database server somewhere for your application to use.

Comment: How can i run the Derby database server

Comment: thank you...                                           i got answer from http://aparna-java.blogspot.in/2011/11/good-day-all.html              it's so good explanation...